# Сохранение файла PHP

Tags: php, xml, файлы, link

Создается XML файл, который с сохраняется в папку files.
После создания появляется ссылка на скачивание.

```
echo "<a href='download.php?file=$file'>Сохранить xml-документ</a>"
```

Как можно его скачать, сразу же, после создания?

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Location: download.php?file=$file");
```

Answer (score 0):

C помощью функции [header](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php) отправляем заголовок [Location](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) со значением ссылки на скачивание файла.

```
header("Location: $link");
```